# Subnets creation failed due to missing Network Security Group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-bicep

I have multiple layers of Bicep files. First I have a powershell script, where I am calling the what-if function

```
         $TEMPLATEFILE="./infra-as-code/bicep/orchestration/hubPeeredSpoke/hubPeeredSpoke.bicep"
        Write-Host $paramsJson

        $updatedParamsJson = $updatedParamsJson.Replace('"', '\"')
        if ($action -eq "whatif") {
            az deployment mg what-if --name $NAME --location $LOCATION --management-group-id $MGID --template-file $TEMPLATEFILE --parameters "$paramsJson" --debug
        }
```

Output of $paramsJson looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "parAllowSpokeForwardedTraffic": {
      "value": false
    },
    "parSpokeNetworkName": {
      "value": "vnet-02-prod"
    },
    "parSubnets": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "sub-001-prod",
          "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Disabled",
          "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
          "addressPrefix": "100.100.100.90/24",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-prod-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-001"
          },
          "delegations": [
            {
              "name": "private",
              "serviceName": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

hubPeeredSpoke.bicep file looks like this:

```
param parSubnets array = []
module modSpokeNetworking '../../modules/spokeNetworking/spokeNetworking.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(parPeeredVnetSubscriptionId, parResourceGroupNameForSpokeNetworking)
  name: varModuleDeploymentNames.modSpokeNetworking
  dependsOn: [
    modResourceGroup
  ]
  params: {
    parSpokeNetworkName: parSpokeNetworkName
    parSpokeNetworkAddressPrefix: parSpokeNetworkAddressPrefix
    parDdosProtectionPlanId: parDdosProtectionPlanId
    parDnsServerIps: parDnsServerIps
    parNextHopIpAddress: varNextHopIPAddress
    parSpokeToHubRouteTableName: parSpokeToHubRouteTableName
    parDisableBgpRoutePropagation: parDisableBgpRoutePropagation
    parTags: parTags
    parTelemetryOptOut: parTelemetryOptOut
    parLocation: parLocation
    parSubnets: parSubnets
  }
}
```

spokeNetworking.bicep file looks like this:

```
param parSubnets array = []
resource resSpokeVirtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-02-01' = {
  name: parSpokeNetworkName
  location: parLocation
  tags: parTags
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        parSpokeNetworkAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    enableDdosProtection: (!empty(parDdosProtectionPlanId) ? true : false)
    ddosProtectionPlan: (!empty(parDdosProtectionPlanId) ? true : false) ? {
      id: parDdosProtectionPlanId
    } : null
    dhcpOptions: (!empty(parDnsServerIps) ? true : false) ? {
      dnsServers: parDnsServerIps
    } : null
    subnets: parSubnets
  }
}
```

The error that I am getting during deployment when I am executing powershell script is:

> RequestDisallowedByPolicy - Resource 'vnet-02-prod' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{"policyAssignment":{"name":"Subnets should have a Network Security Group","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/landingzones/alz/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg"},"policyDefinition":{"name":"Subnets should have a Network Security Group","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/alz/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg"}}]'.

I can't understand how this error shows when parSubnets parameter is populated. When it is not populated, its value is empty array - []

Comment: can you try deploying the vnet hardcoding all the values? wondering if there is an issue with the policy: because the whole subnet is a paramter, it may cause some issue

Comment: You are right. It works fine if I hard code the parameters individually (in a bit different format). If I try the same format to pass as one parameter parSubnets then it is not working anymore

Comment: good to here. not sure if you have access to the policy and can update it?

Comment: The resource you’re trying to deploy doesn’t comply with your Azure Policy. See: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-policy-requestdisallowedbypolicy?tabs=azure-cli